# join three mongoDB collections to generate csv table

Tags: mongodb, csv, nosql

say I have three collections

`users`

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": String
  },
  "username": String,
}
```

`marks`

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": String
  },
  "user_id": String,
  "exam_id": String,
  "question_id": String,
  "mark": String
}
```

and `questions`

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": String
  },
  "exam_id": String,
  "text": String,
}
```

**How to make a csv file like this:** (assume `exam_id` is known)

|  | question1.text | question2.text | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| user1.username | mark | mark | ... |
| user2.username | mark | mark | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

What I have now:

```
const ws = fs.createWriteStream("result.csv");
const fastcsv = require("fast-csv");
const db = MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017', { useUnifiedTopology: true }).db('exam');

db.collection('users')
     .aggregate([
         {
             $lookup:
             {
                 from: 'marks',
                 localField: '_id',
                 foreignField: 'user_id',
                 as: 'marks_doc'
             }
         }
     ])
    //.find({'exam_id': exam_id})
    .toArray(function(err, doc) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(doc);

        fastcsv.write(doc, {headers: true}).on("finish", function() {
            console.log('done!');
        }).pipe(ws);

        db.close();
    });
```

Comment: I would suggest to create a view and then use [mongoexport](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/program/mongoexport/#mongoexport-fields-example) to create the CSV file - should be faster than your approach.